# How to indicate in a human readable way that a function is returned within a function in scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

As a beginner in scala, I have written a method in scala that returns another function:

```
def foo(fnords: Seq[Fnord]): Poit => Boolean {
  (poit: Poit) => {
      fnords.contains(poit.fnord)
  }
}
```

I noticed that I was often confused by my own line of codes wondering why I would return

```
fnords.contains(poit.fnord)
```

even though I in fact correctly return the entire function:

```
(poit: Poit) => {
  fnords.contains(poit.fnord)
}
```

I am wondering if one can make it more explicit to the human eye that a callable is returned or if this is something one has to become used to when writing scala.

Possible ways I found was using the `return` explicitly, which then the linter warns against via "Return keyword is redundant":

```
def foo(fnords: Seq[Fnord]): Poit => Boolean {
  return (poit: Poit) => {
      fnords.contains(poit.fnord)
  }
}
```

I know that I could store the function inside a variable, yet it also feels like doing an explicit return without writing return:

```
def foo(fnords: Seq[Fnord]): Poit => Boolean {
  val filterFunction = (poit: Poit) => {
      fnords.contains(poit.fnord)
  }

  filterFunction
}
```

Is there another way to provide feedback that a callable is returned in scala?

Answer (score 1):

You can write it either as function

```
def foo(fnords: Seq[Fnord]): Poit => Boolean =
    (poit: Poit) => fnords.contains(poit.fnord)
```

or just

```
def foo(fnords: Seq[Fnord]): Poit => Boolean =
    poit => fnords.contains(poit.fnord)
```

or as method

```
def foo(fnords: Seq[Fnord])(poit: Poit): Boolean =
    fnords.contains(poit.fnord)
```

and use it

```
val f: Poit => Boolean = foo(Seq(fnord))
f(poit)
```

To my taste

```
def foo(fnords: Seq[Fnord]): Poit => Boolean = {
  val filterFunction = (poit: Poit) => fnords.contains(poit.fnord)

  filterFunction
}
```

is ok.

Comment: Ah I see you omitted the redundant braces ;)